# Trying to write coredata to csv using chcsvparser

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv

I've done the following to put a fetched request into an array of arrays but now i don't know which methods i need to call from chcsvparser to write this into a csv file

```
NSArray *objectsForExport = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
NSArray *exportKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"best_checkout", @"darts_thrown", @"high_score", @"score_100", @"score_140", @"score_180",@"three_dart_average",nil];

NSMutableArray *csvObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[objectsForExport count]];
for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsForExport) {
    NSMutableArray *anObjectArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[exportKeys count]];
    for (NSString *key in exportKeys) {
        id value = [object valueForKey:key];
        if (!value) {
            value = @"";
        }
        [anObjectArray addObject:[value description]];
    }
    [csvObjects addObject:anObjectArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This webpage should give you the necessary information and methods when writing CSV files:

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser#readme

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I've read that several times but i don't understand which methods i need to call.

Comment: I've tried it like this but it the string appears to be empty:  [csvObjects writeToCSVFile:exportString atomically:NO];
 NSLog(@"exportString %@",exportString);

Answer (score 1):

As Johann suggests, you should use the `writeToCSVFile:atomically:` convenience method. However, be aware that using it as you describe in your comment is not correct.

The NSString you pass in should be the filepath you want the data writing to.